# Creating A store in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I am creating a Store in ASP.NET MVC 5. I have gotten stuck here in the details ActionMethod. I have created the store to show Genres then Specific albums for that genre. Now i need to show the details of any single album that the user clicks on.

public class StoreController : Controller
    {`
    enter code here
        private MVCMusicStoreDB db = new MVCMusicStoreDB();
        // GET: Store

```
    public ActionResult Browse()
    {



        return View(db.Genres.ToList());

    }



    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {



        var albums = db.Albums.Where(a => a.GenreId==id);

        return View(db.Albums.ToList ());


    }
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {


        var album = db.Albums;

        return View();

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{

    var albums = db.Albums.Where(a => a.GenreId==id).ToList();

    return View(albums);   //Here u will return the albums with GenderId = Id
}
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var album = db.Albums.Where(a=>a.AlbumId == id).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(album ); //Here u will return the albums with AlbumId = Id

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your Albums DbSet has a key named `Id`

On your `Details` action use this code to get one unique album

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var album = db.Albums.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(album);
    }
```

Comment: I have plugged in this code but i am still having the same issue. I am not showing any info on the details page. Show i upload a Screenshot?

Comment: Yeap, show your error and add more details on your question

Comment: I figured out the issue. You were right. Instead of (album) i needed to put (id).

Comment: Good news, if you really think my answer is useful mark how the answer in stack overflow